# Combining multiple dataframe columns into a single time series

Tags: dataframe, finance

I have built a financial model in python where I can enter sales and profit for x years in y scenarios - a base scenario plus however many I add.

Annual figures are uploaded per scenario in my first dataframe (e.g. if x = 5 beginning in 2022 then the base scenario sales column would show figures for 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025 and 2026)

I then use monthly weightings to create a monthly phased sales forecast in a new dataframe with the title Base sales 2022 and figures shown monthly, base sales 2023, base sales 2024 etc

I want to show these figures in a single series, so that I have a single times series for base sales of Jan 2022 to Dec 2026 for charting and analysis purposes.

I've managed to get this to work by creating a list and manually adding the names of each column I want to add but this will not work if I have a different number of scenarios or years so am trying to automate the process but can't find a way where I can do this.

I don't want to share my main model coding but I have created a mini model doing a similar thing below but it doesn't work as although it generates most of the output I want (three lists are requested listA0, listA1, listA2), the lists clearly aren't created as they aren't callable. Also, I really need all the text in a single line rather than split over multiple lines (or perhaps I should use list append for each susbsequent item). Any help gratefully received.

Below is the code I have tried:

```
#Create list of scenarios and capture the number for use later
Scenlist=["Bad","Very bad","Terrible"]
Scen_number=3
#Create the list of years under assessment and count the number of years
Years=[2020,2021,2022]
Totyrs=len(Years)
#Create the dataframe dprofit and for example purposes create the columns, all showing two datapoints 10 and 10

dprofit=pd.DataFrame()
a=0
b=0

#This creates column names in the format Bad profit 2020, Bad profit 2021 etc

while a<Scen_number:
  while b<Totyrs:
    dprofit[Scenlist[a]+" profit "+str(Years[b])]=[10,10]
    b=b+1
  b=0
  a=a+1

#Now that the columns have been created print the table

print(dprofit)

#Now create the new table profit2 which will be used to capture the three columns (bad, very bad and terrible) for the full time period by listing the years one after another
dprofit2=pd.DataFrame()
#Create the output to recall the columns from dprofit to combine into 3 lists listA0, list A1 and list A2

a=0
b=0
Totyrs=len(Years)
while a<Scen_number:
   while b<Totyrs:
    if b==0:
      print(f"listA{a}=dprofit[{Scenlist[a]} profit {Years[b]}]")
    else:
      print(f"+dprofit[{Scenlist[a]} profit {Years[b]}]")
    b=b+1
  b=0
  a=a+1
print(listA0)

#print(list A0) will not call as NameError: name 'listA0' is not defined. Did you mean: 'list'?
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the printing you could set the `end` param to `end=''`.

```py
while a < Scen_number:
    while b < Totyrs:
        if b == 0:
            print(f"listA{a}=dprofit[{Scenlist[a]} profit {Years[b]}]", end="")
        else:
            print(f"+dprofit[{Scenlist[a]} profit {Years[b]}]", end="")
        results.append([Scenlist[a], Years[b]])
        b = b + 1
    print()
    b = 0
    a = a + 1
```

**Output:**

```
listA0=dprofit[Bad profit 2020]+dprofit[Bad profit 2021]+dprofit[Bad profit 2022]
listA1=dprofit[Very bad profit 2020]+dprofit[Very bad profit 2021]+dprofit[Very bad profit 2022]
listA2=dprofit[Terrible profit 2020]+dprofit[Terrible profit 2021]+dprofit[Terrible profit 2022]
```

To obtain a list or pd.DataFrame of the columns, you could simply [filter()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for the required columns. No loop required.

```py
listA0 = dprofit.filter(regex="Bad profit", axis=1)
listA1 = dprofit.filter(regex="Very bad profit", axis=1)
listA2 = dprofit.filter(regex="Terrible profit", axis=1)
print(listA1)
```

**Output for `listA1`:**

```
   Very bad profit 2020  Very bad profit 2021  Very bad profit 2022
0                    10                    10                    10
1                    10                    10                    10
```